# How to efficiently circulate air to keep room cool?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I live in Indonesia and I have an apartment with a 6.7 x 5m room, which contains a dining table and a couch. In this room are two 1.5PK (13,000 BTU) AC units on the same side of room nearer to the couch. If I turn on both ACs I think it's cool enough when I'm sitting on the couch because it's quite near the AC, but not at the dining table. I can barely feel any breeze at the dining table and so it's unpleasant sitting there. This is when only I am in the room. I can't imagine what it's like when I'm having guests.. I was suggested to install stronger ACs, but I fear that's gonna be costly and also it'll be freezing cold near the couch but so-so cold at the dining table.

I think the two AC units are cool enough, but perhaps the cool air is not circulating to all corners of the room. What is your suggestion to keep the whole room evenly cool?

[image]

[image]

[image]
Thank you very much

Comment: Was the a/c correctly sized for the climate, building construction, room size, and occupancy?

Comment: @wallyk Sorry I am not an expert in this field. I can only tell you what I currently feel when both ACs are on and that is cool near the couch and warm at the dining table. Like I originally wrote I was suggested by someone else to replace with 2 units of 2 PK ACs, but if the cool air is not circulating then I fear it's gonna be freezing cold near the couch and luke warm anyway at the dining table. I think the real solution is to install one of the ACs on the wall across and opposite side of the room, but unfortunately that is not possible.

Comment: You don't need to be an expert to know if one was involved in the installation of the cooling system or if local building codes require that it be done professionally and/or to code.  The installation certainly looks well done, but I can see only a little bit in the latter photo.  Have you looked to see if the wall units have any type of fan adjustment?  Maybe a blower speed (low/medium/hi).  Or a way to divert the airflow across the room instead of straight down?  Also, climbing up there and taking a peek inside might reveal dust clogging the airflow.

Comment: @wallyk Well the units do have those controls on the remote. Air speed and direction. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

A common method of equalizing the temperature across a room is to add a [ceiling fan](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Hawkins-44-in-White-Ceiling-Fan-YG204-WH/100630902#.UiN9f2TF3D0). 
[image: ceiling fan]

Cool air tends to stay near the floor, and a fan can be set to pull the air upwards.  As it hits the ceiling, the air is pushed outwards to the edges of the room. Because cool air is heavier than warm air, it then moves downward, better distributing the temperature.

A very low setting can be used to avoid noise and strong air currents.  This is easier with fans that have variable speeds, which is common with remote control types.

This technique is also used to circulate warm air for heating systems that need help with temperature distribution.

SUPPLEMENT

The ceiling fan should be placed near the center of the room. Most fans are reversible. The fan should be set to blow upward, if possible.

[Floor fans](http://www.homedepot.com/p/HDX-20-in-High-Velocity-Floor-Fan-SFC1-500BI/202757016#.UiN-U2TF3D0) can also be used.

[image: floor fan]

Similarly, a [pedestal fan](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lasko-Cyclone-18-in-Adjustable-Pedestal-Fan-1823/202563946#.UiN-zWTF3D1).

[image: pedestal fan]

If using a floor or pedestal fan, place near the air conditioning flow and direct the fan upward and toward the other end of the room.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Based on the blueprint where would you suggest placing the fan. Do you have any pictures as an example?

Comment: Edited with pictures. Hope they help.

Comment: By the way will floor fans work? I'm not keen on installing another ceiling fan as it will require quite a bit of construction... Would prefer something reasonably portable. Like a Dyson one maybe? Thanks @bib

Comment: Do you have a manual for your AC units? Is the fan speed adjustable? Is the airflow direction adjustable?

Comment: @PhilipNgai yes. Fan speed is adjustable to Low, Medium, Heigh. Airflow direction is also adjustable by its Swing and left-right direction. How does that help me?

Comment: @bib thanks a lot for the additional detail. I will experiment with floor or pedestal fans. I have always wanted a Dyson fan and now have a good excuse to get one :D

Comment: The underlying issue is a lack of air circulation. I would assume you have tried your AC adjustments (set speed to high and airflow direction to cover the whole room) and if that is true, then you need some kind of external fan to help the AC. rabbid seems to have covered the common choices. In my opinion a ceiling fan is most effective but not suitable to your room's style. I would also add that the "vortex" fans have an amazing "throw" and are worth the extra price. Vornado is one brand on the market.